# How can I execute Javascript code in C# (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

I am exploring the possibilities of Blockly and would like to take the code generated by Blockly, store it in database and run it later. Of course it will not be executed in a View. I understand that Javascript is a client language but is there a way I can execute Javascript code in C#?

Comment: https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Chromium Embedded Framework` has **C#** bindings: `CefSharp`

It will run your **JavaScript** and it can work without UI or rendering the result if you need:

https://cefsharp.github.io/

The FAQ contains a specific answer to your question, too:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS